# Devise: "remember_me" works in development, but not in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am using Devise for authentification through a JSON request. It works except for `remember_me` in rspec feature test, however it works when using curl through my development server. I am certainly doing something wrong, any help appreciated

Feature spec:

```
it 'Log in with "remember_me"' do
  user = create :user
  params = {user: {email: user.email, password: 'debug', remember_me: '1'}}
  post '/api/v1/auth/sign_in', params, format: :json
  response.status.should eq(201) # created
  response.cookies.has_key?('_my_app_session').should eq(true)
  response.cookies.has_key?('remember_user_token').should eq(true)
end
```

This fails at the last line with `expected: true got: false`

Command line:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  -X POST -d '{"user":{"email":"maeva_morel@deschamps.fr","password":"debug","remember_me":"1"}}' \
  http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in
```

This works as there is in the output

```
Set-Cookie: remember_user_token=W1s3Nl0sIiQyYSQxMCRoOERF...
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What are gem versions? I don't see any similar issues in google

Comment: Thanks for your concern, I checked on that and found nothing wrong. However I found that cookie is signed, therefore not included in `response.cookies`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remember_me` is stored in a signed cookie, therefore not available in `response.cookies`

To fix you must replace the last line of the test by:

```
@request.cookie_jar.has_key?('remember_user_token').should eq(true)
```

Comment: Or use non-encrypted cookies in test.